# How to enable streaming replication in PostgreSQL running in kubernetes pods?

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, kubernetes, containers

From what I have read, I need to make changes to the configuration file `postgres.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` and after that we need to create a "replication" user.

1. How do I make changes to these configuration files and make sure that the changes to these configuration files persist through the restarts?
2. Since my postgres is running inside a kubernetes pod, I reckon that the user must be created inside the container.
   But when I do `createuser -replication -P replica`, it wont allow me to create one since the current user after I did `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` is `root` and not `postgres`.

Comment: *the current user is root and not postgres* then `su postgres -c "createuser -replication -P replica"` should sort that problem out

Answer (score 3):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/avshabanov/eb8e03a050c79f8e77420b06f9b4abe5) has a detailed explanation on how to setup a master-slave replication with Postgres using docker.

### Master configuration

#### Create replication_user

```
CREATE USER replication_user NOSUPERUSER;
ALTER USER replication_user WITH REPLICATION;
ALTER USER replication_user WITH PASSWORD 'CHANGEME';
```

#### postgresql.conf

Edit or add these lines:

```
listen_addresses = '*'   # It can be more specific with the listen IP
wal_level = hot_standby  
max_wal_sender = 5       #  Specifies the maximum number of concurrent connections from standby servers
ssl = off
archive_mode = on   
archive_command = "cp %p /path/to/archive/%f"
```

#### pg_hba.conf

Let's suppose that 192.168.0.2/32 is the IP of the slave and replication_user is the replication user.

**case no authentication is required**

```
 host  replication   replication_user   192.168.0.2/32      trust
```

**case authentication using password**

```
 host  replication   replication_user   192.168.0.2/32      scram-sha-256 # or MD5
```

### Slave configuration

Let's suppose that the Master IP is: 192.168.0.1 and the port is the default (5432).

```
listen_addresses = '*'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication_user password=CHANGEME host=192.168.0.1 port=5432'
hot_standby = on
```

### Making the configuration persistent

You can use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) (or [for kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)).
Start by creating the configuration files in the local machine that start the containers and then:

```
docker run --rm --name IMAGE_NAME -v /local/path/to/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf -v /local/path/to/pg_hba.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf CONTAINER_NAME
```

The same for the slaves.

## sources:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication

https://gist.github.com/avshabanov/eb8e03a050c79f8e77420b06f9b4abe5

Comment: the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide recommends giving at least a "tl;dr" when providing link-only answers, because link rot is a very real thing

Comment: no, as described by the page that I referenced, you want to provide a summary of the link **contents** -- how would you feel stumbling upon your answer next week only to find that link produces a 404? what value would you have contributed?